# How can I count the amount of negative numbers in an arrary in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

I have written a few programs in MASM such as one that is able to produce a triangle out of letters and spaces depending on the number you give it and one that is able to add and subtract and show you as it is doing it with numbers you give it so I hope this gives you an idea about how much MASM I know. 
My question is this. I have been given an array that contains numbers of either positive or neg. My job is to go through the array and figure out which is which and return the number of negatives in the array. I understand what the code I put means and what all the individual elements mean and do but I wanted to know if you all could help me in trying to figure out how to distinguish between the neg and positive numbers so I can implement it.

```
;; Do not modify this block of code 
;; (until where comment says you can start your code)
;;
    call Clrscr
    call Randomize       ; Initialize random number generator

;;;;; Generate NUM_NUMS random numbers and store them into the nums array

    mov ecx,NUM_NUMS     ; Number of times to loop
    mov esi,0            ; Relative offset for nums array

NUM_LOOP:
    call Random32        ; Generate a random number
    mov [nums+esi], eax  ; Move random number into array

    add esi,TYPE nums    ; move esi to relative offset of next array element
    LOOP NUM_LOOP        ; end of loop

;;
;; End of do not modify block
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. For example (none of these are tested, by the way, and loop logic not shown to keep it short)

```
 1:
  cmp [nums+esi], 0 ; compare with 0
  jnl _skip
  inc edx           ; increment count if < 0
_skip:
 2:
  mov eax, [nums+esi]
  test eax, eax     ; update sign flag with sign bit
  jns _skip
  inc edx           ; increment count if sign was set (ie, < 0)
_skip:
 3:
  mov eax, [nums+esi]
  add eax, eax      ; create unsigned overflow if < 0
  jnc _skip
  inc edx           ; increment count if overflowed (ie, < 0)
_skip:
 4:
  mov eax, [nums+esi]
  shl eax, 1        ; same as 3, but an other way to create overflow
  jnc _skip
  inc edx
_skip:
 5:
  mov eax, [nums+esi]
  add eax, eax
  adc edx, 0        ; add the overflow directly to the count
 6:
  mov eax, [nums+esi]
  shl eax, 1
  adc edx, 0        ; same as 5
_skip:
 7:
  mov eax, [nums+esi]
  sar eax, 31       ; create 0 if non-negative, -1 if negative
  sub edx, eax      ; subtract -1 from count if negative
 8:
  mov eax, [nums+esi]
  shr eax, 31       ; create 0 if non-negative, 1 if negative
  add edx, eax      ; add 1 to count if negative
 9:
  movdqa xmm0, [nums + esi]
  psrad xmm0, 31
  psubd xmm1, xmm0   ; same idea as 7, but with 4 in parallel
 10:
  movdqa xmm0, [nums + esi]
  psrld xmm0, 31
  paddd xmm1, xmm0   ; same idea as 8, but with 4 in parallel
 11:
  cmp [nums+esi], 0
  lea eax, [edx + 1] ; create count+1
  cmovl edx, eax     ; update count with incremented count if < 0
 12:
  xor eax, eax
  cmp [nums+esi], eax
  setl al            ; 0 if non-negative, 1 if negative
  add edx, eax
 13:
  cmp [nums+esi], 0
  setl al
  movzx eax, al    ; same idea as 12, but no recombination penalty
  add edx, eax
```

And endless variations. Take your pick.

Comment: Quite sure. Only the first time the msb of eax must be zero. The logic takes care of it next time. Just wanted to add it for sake of obfuscation.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen but what's up with that 32-bit `setcc`? I didn't even know we had that, but it would be pretty awesome

Comment: Yes indeed. It spoils the obfuscation part. Have to do it as `cmp [array], 0; setn al; add edx, eax;` with eax cleared once. Maybe that's the reason, why setcc is seen so rarely anyway.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen pity, it was a nice trick. I've seen a 32bit `setcc` proposed on sirrida, so maybe someday..

Comment: I thought it was going to be alot harder than that but once I catch the drift of where you were going with it I understood it. I just hate how it's not very direct with you but once you get an idea of what goes where and what does what, assembly is pretty fun. I only shutter at the thought of having to write an entire program in assembly lol.